# Can Cassandra or ScyllaDB give incomplete data while reading with PySpark if either clusters are left un-repaired forever?

Tags: pyspark, cassandra, scylla

I use both Cassandra and ScyllaDB 3-node clusters and use PySpark to read data. I was wondering if any of them are not repaired forever, is there any challenge while reading data from either if there are inconsistencies in nodes. Will the correct data be read and if yes, then why do we need to repair them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can get incorrect data if reapir is not done. It also depends on with what consistency you are reading or writing. Generally in production systems writes are done with (Local_one/Local_quorum) and read with Local_quorum.

If you are writing with weak consistency level, then repair becomes important as some of the nodes might not have got the mutations and while reading those nodes may get selected.

For example if you write with consistency level `ONE` on a table `TABLE1` with a replication of 3. Now it may happen your write was written to `NodeA` only and `NodeB` and `NodeC` might have missed the mutation. Now if you are reading with Consistency level `LOCAL_QUORUM`, it may happen that `NodeB` and 'NodeC' get selected and they do not return the written data.

Repair is an important maintenance task for Cassandra which should be done periodically and continuously to keep data in healthy state.

Comment: The reading is done with LOCAL_ONE and writing is done with LOCAL_QUORUM as they are both default's of Datastax Spark Cassandra Connector. So, in this case will I still get incorrect data without repair?

Comment: Yes, some nodes may miss the mutations when you write with LOCAL_QUORUM and you may read from those nodes while reading.

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted in other answers, different consistency levels make repair more or less important for different reasons. So I'll focus on the consistency level that you said in a comment you are using: LOCAL_ONE for reading and LOCAL_QUORUM for writing:

Successfully writing with LOCAL_QUORUM only guarantees that two replicas have been written. If the third replica is temporarily down, and will later come up - at that point one third of the read requests for this data, reads done from only one node (this is what LOCAL_ONE means) will miss the new data! Moreover, there isn't even a guarantee of so-called *monotonic consistency* - you can get new data in one read (from one node), and the old data in a later read (from another node).

However, it isn't completely accurate that only a repair can fix this problem. Another feature - enabled by default on both Cassandra and Scylla - is called [Hinted Handoff](https://docs.scylladb.com/architecture/anti-entropy/hinted-handoff/) - where when a node is down for relatively short time (up to three hours, but also depending on the amount of traffic in that period), other nodes which tried to send it updates remember those updates - and retry the send when the dead node comes back up. If you are faced only with such relatively short downtimes, repair isn't necessary and Hinted Handoff is actually enough.

That being said, Hinted Handoff isn't guaranteed perfect and might miss some inconsistencies. E.g., the node wishing to save a hint might itself be rebooted before it managed to save the hint, or replaced after saving it. So this mechanism isn't completely foolproof.

By the way, there another thing you need to be aware of: If you **ever** intend to do a repair (e.g., perhaps after some node was down for too long for Hinted Handoff to have worked, or perhaps because a QUORUM read causes a *read repair*), you must do it at least once every `gc_grace_seconds` (this defaults to 10 days).
The reason for this statement is the risk of **data resurrection** by repair which is too infrequent. The thing is, after `gc_grace_seconds`, the *tombstones* marking deleted items are removed forever ("garbage collected"). At that point, if you do a repair and one of the nodes happens to have an old version of this data (prior to the delete), the old data will be "resurrected" - copied to all replicas.

Comment: Good callout on running repair once every `gc_grace_seconds`.  Plus 1 from me!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Manish's great answer, I'll just add that read operations run consistency levels *higher* than `*_ONE` have a (small...10% default) chance to invoke a [read repair](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesReadRepair.html).  I have seen that applications running at a higher consistency level for reads, will have less issues with inconsistent replicas.

Although, writing at `*_QUORUM` should ensure that the majority (quorum) of replicas are indeed consistent.  Once it's written successfully, data should not "go bad" over time.

That all being said, running periodic (weekly) repairs is a good idea.  I highly recommend using [Cassandra Reaper](http://cassandra-reaper.io/) to manage repairs, especially if you have multiple clusters.